# Passport.js Local Strategy Auth Config

Tags: node.js, rest, passport-local, passport.js

I'm following the passport.js authentication tutorial provided by [scotch.io](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local), and it is actually working on my browser, but since I'm developing a REST API I'm slowing changing some parts of the code, e.g. no need for ejs module. I'm trying to sign up an user with post requests using chrome's Postman alongside Basic Auth, but to no avail so far, the authentication always fails and redirects to signup again. Here's the sign up post:

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/login', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

Can someone explain to me why is it no working with post requests not made through the signup.ejs template, and how can I change scotch implementation to something REST like?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the `<input>` names in your new template? This is most likely the reason. Passport looks for two input field names: `username` and `password`. If those aren't present no credentials will be found.